# Making my step definition prettier

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I'm writing a step definition that will take in an http request type (get, post, etc), the url of the api, and a table of data to send from gherkin. I implemented it the following way, but its a very imperative style and isn't necessarily that clear to other testers what's going on. It constructs requests from a table like this

```
| x | y |
| 1 | 2 |
| 5 | 7 |
```

such that the requests are sent using JSON and in this case two are sent, with the following JSON:

```
{
  "x":"1"
  "y":"2"
}
```

and

```
{
  "x":"5"
  "y":"7"
}
```

In other words, each row after the first represent a request with specific values of the variables from the first row.

My implementation below, any more readable refactors are welcome. Thanks.

```
When(/^I submit the following (?:in)?valid data in a "(.*?)" request to "(.*?)"$/) do |request_type, api, table|
  data = table.raw
  for i in 1...data.length #rows
    body = {}
    for j in 0...data[0].length #cols
      body[data[0][j]] = data[i][j]
    end
    @response = HTTParty.__send__ request_type, "/a/url#{api}", { 
        :body => body.to_json,
        :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }
    }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write something like this:

```
When(/^I submit the following (?:in)?valid data in a "(.*?)" request to "(.*?)"$/) do |method, api, table|
  data = table.raw
  keys = data.shift

  data.each do |line|
    hash = Hash[*keys.zip(line)]
    @response = build_request(api, method, hash)
  end
end

# with this helper method
def build_request(api, method, hash)
  HTTParty.__send__(method, 
                    "/a/url#{api}", 
                    { :body    => hash.to_json,
                      :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' } })
end
```

Comment: A helper method is a definite plus. I'll check this out and it looks like I'll learn more about Ruby on the way.